# Switching column in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Yet another question about Notepad++. I would like to switch 2 columns using the Find and replace tool (very long document).

I have this:

```
1,40 48 56.85,-26 37 17.64,1
2,40 46 4.78,-26 42 30.45,2
3,40 37 5.82,-27 10 8.34,3
4,40 3 10.38,-27 42 26.51,4
5,40 30 22.18,-28 35 11.00,5
6,40 11 6.42,-28 59 21.62,6
7,39 49 10.33,-29 33 28.46,7
```

But I need this:

```
1,-26 37 17.64,40 48 56.85,1
2,-26 42 30.45,40 46 4.78,2
3,-27 10 8.34,40 37 5.82,3
4,-27 42 26.51,40 3 10.38,4
5,-28 35 11.00,40 30 22.18,5
6,-28 59 21.62,40 11 6.42,6
7,-29 33 28.46,39 49 10.33,7
```

So basically switching the 2 columns in the middle. The expressions I tried didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do:

Find what: `^([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)$`
Replace with: `$1,$3,$2,$4`

Make sure that `regular expression` is checked and click on `Replace All`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible for you to align those columns (a kind of 'fixed column width'), you can easily select the entire column, holding the Alt key down and drag with you mouse the entire column, after that (vertical) selection you can easily move it.